# openshift: how to force directory content refresh without restarting the application

Tags: file-upload, openshift

I have uploaded (via SFTP) a new version of a php script in my openshift application space. However, I had to restart the application since the runned script appears the previous version. Is there any way to force a refresh of updated files without the need to restart application every time I upload a new version of some script? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](https://blog.openshift.com/more-online-features-for-april-2014/), set APC_ENABLED to false, also when you SFTP straight to root, be mindful if you git push because you will be overwritten by the git repo....since the repo wasnt amended as you sftp-ed....back yourself up...

> Configure PHP APC With this latest release we’ve created a way for you
>   Enable/Disable APC opcode cache in your PHP app. While APC is enabled
>   by default, you can disable/re-enable APC by running rhc env-set
>   OPENSHIFT_PHP_APC_ENABLED=false --app . Once again, we’ve
>   provided some new environment variables to make this change even
>   easier.
>
> $OPENSHIFT_PHP_APC_ENABLED=true/false
>   $OPENSHIFT_PHP_APC_SHM_SIZE={64,128,256}MB